# Search and replace sub-patterns using regex

Tags: regex, pcre, textwrangler

I'm trying to use regular expressions to search/replace sub-patterns but I seem to be stuck. Note: I'm using TextWrangler on OSX to complete this.

***SCENARIO:***

Here is an example of a complete match:

```
{constant key0="variable/three" anotherkey=$variable.inside.same.match key2="" thirdkey='exists'}
```

Each match will always:

- start with the following: `{constant key0=`
- terminate with a single curly brace: `}`
- contain one or more `key=value` pairs

  - the key of the first pair is constant (in this case, the key is `key0`)
  - the value of the first pair is variable (in this case, the value is `"variable/three"`)
  - each additional pairs, if any, are separated by whitespace

Here's an example of what a minimal (but complete) match would look like (with only one `key=value` pair):

```
{constant key0="first/variable/example"}
```

Here's another example of a valid match, but with trailing whitespace after the last (and only) `key=value` pair:

```
{constant key0="same/as/above/but/with/whitespace/after/quote" }
```

***GOAL:***

**What I need to be able to do is extract each `key` and each `value` from each match and then rearrange them.** For example, I might need the following:

```
{constant key0="variable/4" variable_key_1="yes" variable_key_2=0}
```

... to look like this after all is said and done:

```
$variable_key_1 = "yes"; $variable_key_2 = 0; {newword "variable/4"}
```

... where

- a `$` has been added to the extracted keys
- spaces have been added between each `key=value` pair's `=`
- a `;` has been appended to each extracted value
- the word `constant` has been changed to `newword`, and
- `key0=` has been removed completely.

Here are some examples of what I've tried (note that the first one actually works, but only when there is exactly one key/value pair):

```
Search:
(\{constant\s+key0=\s*)([^\}\s]+)(\s*\})
Replace:
{newword \2}

Search:
(\{constant\s+key0=)([^\s]+)(([\s]+[^\s]+)([\s]*=\s*)([^\}]+)+)(\s*\})
Replace:
I wasn't able to come up with a good way to replace the output of this one.
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the nature of this match, it's actually three different regexes—one to figure out what the match is, and two others to process the matches. Now, I don't know how you intend to *escape* the quotes, so I'll give one for each common escapement system.
Without further ado, here's the set for the **backslash** escapement system:

```
Find:
\{constant\s+key0=([^\s"]\S*|"(\\.|[^\\"])*")(\s+[^\s=]+=([^\s"]\S*|"(\\.|[^\\"])*"))*\s*\}
Search 1:
(?<=\s)([^\s=]+)=([^\s"]\S*|"(\\.|[^\\"])*")(?=.*\})
Replace 1:
$1 = $2;
Search 2:
^\{constant\s+key0 = ([^\s"]\S*|"(\\.|[^\\"])*");\s*(?=\S)(.*)\}
Replace 2:
$2 {newword $1}
```

Now the **URL/XML/HTML** escapement system, much easier to parse:

```
Find:
\{constant\s+key0=([^\s"]\S*|"[^"]*")(\s+[^\s=]+=([^\s"]\S*|"[^"]*"))*\s*\}
Search 1:
(?<=\s)([^\s=]+)=([^\s"]\S*|"[^"]*")(?=.*\})
Replace 1:
$1 = $2;
Search 2:
^\{constant\s+key0 = ([^\s"]\S*|"[^"]*");\s*(?=\S)(.*)\}$
Replace 2:
$2 {newword $1}
```

Hope this helps.